# I want to save 3 entities entry at a time. How to do that

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2, linq-to-entities, entity-framework-4

I Have a view with 3 entity.
When I Click on the submit button, I Would like to save these entities .

**In the view**

```
<div class="editor-field ">
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ElementAt(0).UserQuestion1)%>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ElementAt(0).UserQuestion1)%>
 </div>
<div class="editor-field ">
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ElementAt(0).UserAnswer)%>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ElementAt(0).UserAnswer)%>
</div>

<div class="editor-field ">
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ElementAt(1).UserQuestion1)%>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ElementAt(1).UserQuestion1)%>
 </div>
 <div class="editor-field ">
    <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ElementAt(1).UserAnswer)%>
    <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ElementAt(1).UserAnswer)%>
  </div>

  <div class="editor-field ">
     <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ElementAt(2).UserQuestion1)%>
     <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ElementAt(2).UserQuestion1)%>
  </div>
  <div class="editor-field ">
     <%: Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.ElementAt(2).UserAnswer)%>
     <%: Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.ElementAt(2).UserAnswer)%>
  </div>
```

**In the Controller**

```
    public ActionResult ChooseQuestion()
    {
        List<UserQuestion> lst = new List<UserQuestion>() {
            new UserQuestion(),new UserQuestion(), new UserQuestion()
        };
        return View(lst);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public void ChooseQuestion(List<UserQuestion> lst)
    {
        //lst is always NULL Why
        //EntityFactory.GetEntity().SaveChanges();
    }
```

Why when I Click on submit button, my parameter List lst is null.
I Would like to perform a save.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than element at, try using the model[0] syntax instead.  This is used in the examples I've seen.

HTH.

Comment: this is exacly what I need. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a known number of entities you could construct a custom view model with a different name for each entity. They should be correctly bound when you submit them then.

Comment: I don't know the number of entities, I Use 3 for this example. Thanks for your help.